# Loop through all of the occurrences of a certain string and replace each with a different value in C#?

Tags: c#

I  have a large text string (its a source code), and i need to loop through occurrences of a certain string (which can occur in random number of places), and replace each of them with a different value, which i cannot do using Replace() function considering it replaces all the of them with a unique value.

so for example this text string :

```
REPLACE_ME

REPLACE_ME

REPLACE_ME
```

needs to get converted to this :

```
RAND_STRING1

RAND_STRING2

RAND_STRING3
```

I read the entire text all at once, and already have it in a string variable.

Comment: Do you read the text by chunks with a `TextReader` or all at once ?

Comment: @aybe all at once, and i already have it in a string variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Replace + different number each replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851885/c-sharp-replace-different-number-each-replace)

Comment: It's these kinds of "how to" questions and answers that are precisely the ones this site needs, provided they are sufficiently constrained in scope (which this one is).

Comment: @devNull although both are using the same approach (Regex.Replace), i think Jessen's code is much easier to follow and overall a better answer, thanks everyone i got it.

Comment: @devNull also i think the title of that question is really vague and people will probably have a hard time finding it by googling, "C# Replace + different number each replace" is not really clear.

Comment: @OneAndOnly I found that question by googling :) I do see what you mean though

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto whoops! Probably would have read better with a `,` in there haha.

Comment: @OneAndOnly I've edited a bit that question, hope it makes more sense to you now

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto much better now, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Regex.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) accepts a `MatchEvaluator` delegate with which you can accomplish what you want:

```
var input = "REPLACE_ME REPLACE_ME REPLACE_ME";

var substring = Regex.Escape("REPLACE_ME");
var substitute = "VALUE";
var counter = 1;

var result = Regex.Replace(input, substring, (m) => $"{prefix}{counter++}");
```

Value of `result` will be `"VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3"`.

The `Regex.Escape()` call is redundant for this particular example (`"REPLACE_ME"` doesn't contain any special characters that needs to be escaped), but I suggest getting into the habit of escaping literal substrings regardless - especially if you want to accept user-supplied input!

Of course you can do anything you'd like in the evaluator:

```
var random = new Random();
var result = Regex.Replace(input, substring, (m) => random.Next().ToString());
// or
var result = Regex.Replace(input, substring, (m) => {
    var randomString = someAPIClient.GetRandomValueFromRandomValueService();
    var encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(randomString);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);
});
```

Your imagination sets the limit here :)

Comment: Is it C# 9 or C# 8? I mean you used lambda expression `(m) => `.

Comment: @Bigeyes: The lambda expression is a stand-in for the MatchEvaluator delegate required by the cited `Regex.Replace` overload.  It does not require C# 9.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31326693

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works (with a lambda) as far back as C# 3/.NETFX 3.5 :)

Answer (score 2):

regex example:

```
string[] textFile = File.ReadAllLines("myFile.txt");
var i = 0;
//Stringbuilder will be the contents of our new text file.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//iterate through each line, making our replacements and appending to the string builder
foreach (string line in textFile)
{
    var result = Regex.Replace(
                 line, "REPLACE_ME", m => string.Format("{0}{1}",m.Value,++i), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    sb.AppendLine(result);
}
//Write to new file like so:
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("newFile.txt");
sw.Write(sb.ToString()));
sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the file line by line.
Keep a counter of nr instances found.

If the current line contains your REPLACE_ME string then replace that string with your random string and append the counter value, update the counter + 1 and keep going to the following line.

The result will be that each instance of your replace_me will be replace with a unique value.